# UrlGenerationError Missing Required Key [:id] Error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I want to create an article I get this error after clicking on the create article button

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

although I make sure there is a user who is logged in before creating the article. Here's my code:

**articles_controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user , except:[:index,:show]

  def index
      @articles = Article.all
  end  

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
        flash[:notice] = "Your Article was Created"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update(article_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Your Article was Updated"
        redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Your Article was deleted"
    redirect_to articles_path(@article)
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title,:description)
  end
```

end

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "You Signed up successfully"
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:success]= "Your user was updated"
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username,:email,:password)
  end
```

end

**views/new.html**

```
    <h1>New Article</h1>
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>

<p>title<%= f.text_field :title %></p><br>
<p>description<%= f.text_area :description %></p>
<%= f.submit "Create" %>
<%end%>
```

here's 
[my github repo](http://github.com/Ahmedalthani/BlogApp)

Comment: Please check your create article button link, it is redirecting you to show action of article controller

Comment: in your code `<li> <%= link_to "New", new_article_path(@article)%></li>`. You dont need to give parameters in `new_article_path`. Otherwise, it will check for a article without an `id` , as navin said.

Comment: it still shows the error although i removed the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an invalid article it will give you the `missing required keys: [:id]` since it fails to `@article.save` it will `redirect_to article_path(@article)` in which in this case @article.id is `nil`

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
        flash[:notice] = "Your Article was Created"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

Just move `redirect_to article_path(@article)` if `@article.save` is true.

```
def create
   @article = Article.new(article_params)
   if @article.save
       flash[:notice] = "Your Article was Created"
       redirect_to article_path(@article)
    else
       render 'new'
    end       
end
```

**Edit:**

I cloned your repo and the problem exists when creating the article without `user_id`. added the changes in the bottom and it seem to be working as expected.

```
def create
       @article = current_user.articles.build(article_params)

       if @article.save
           flash[:notice] = "Your Article was Created"
           redirect_to article_path(@article)
        else
           render 'new'
        end       
    end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The issue is when the code moves to the @article.save it won't save the article even though there is a user_id and the title and the description is validated.

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because of **render** and **redirect** both getting executed when **@article.save**  fails.So it goes to else part where it get render to new and again redirects to show page with **id = nil**.

```
def create
   @article = Article.new(article_params)
   if @article.save
       flash[:notice] = "Your Article was Created"
       redirect_to article_path(@article.id) # or @article
    else
       render 'new'
    end       
end
```

Comment: It's still not working. When i click on the Create article button it won't save the article even though i change the create action method to this code. I tried the console and it creates the article fine without any issue.